# Issues using slots and signals when connecting two windows in Qt using PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals, slots

I am having trouble passing a line of text from one LineEdit in a window to a lineEdit in another window by clicking a button. I have read multiple examples but I can't seem to get the signal to display on the second window. This is a very paired down version of the app I'm creating. I hope y'all can see something I can't. The second window will open when the button in the first window is clicked, but nothing happens.

Thanks

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    textSaved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window1,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Signal Signal Emitter")
        self.home()

    def home(self):

        self.__line=QtGui.QLineEdit("howdy", self)
        self.__line.move(120,100)

        btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Send Signal", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.send_signal)
        btn.move(0,100)

        self.show()

    def send_signal(self):
        signal=self.__line.displayText()
        self.textSaved.emit(signal)
        self.Window2=Window2()
        self.Window2.show()

class Window2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Signal Slot Receiver")
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.line_response=QtGui.QLineEdit(None, self)
        self.line_response.move(120,100)

        self.__main=Window1()
        self.__main.textSaved.connect(self.showMessage)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def showMessage(self, message):
        self.bigbox(self, "The message is:"+ message)
        self.show()

def run():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI=Window1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
run()
```

Comment: The `Window2` is created only after `textSaved` signal has already been emitted. Thus, at the time of emit, there are no listeners and the signal is ignored.

Comment: I moved the Window2 class before Window1 class, and moved 

self.Window2=Window2() 
before the emit signal in the send_signal definition but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so there are a few ways you can do this. You're on the right track for the signal slot thing. However, since you have multiple calls in each class to the other class, things get a little messed up.

One way to solve your problem is to simply change the `__init__` function for your `Window2` class so that it accepts text, and sets the `QLineEdit` text to the inputted text. This will work once. When you click the button, the second window will show, and subsequent clicks won't change the text. Look below if you want the button to always update the text in the other window.

**One time click**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    textSaved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window1,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Signal Signal Emitter")
        self.home()

    def home(self):

        self.__line=QtGui.QLineEdit("howdy", self)
        self.__line.move(120,100)

        btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Send Signal", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.send_signal)
        btn.move(0,100)

        self.show()

    def send_signal(self):
        signal=self.__line.displayText()
        self.textSaved.emit(signal)
        self.Window2=Window2(signal)  # instantiate Window2 with the text
        self.Window2.show()

class Window2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.text = txt
        super(Window2,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Signal Slot Receiver")
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.line_response=QtGui.QLineEdit(self.text, self)
        self.line_response.move(120,100)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def showMessage(self, message):
        self.bigbox(self, "The message is:"+ message)
        self.show()

def run():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI=Window1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
run()
```

I also don't know what `self.bigbox` is, do you want that to update? When I tried running it, I changed it to `self.line_response` because that's what I thought you meant.

This solution will work in the sense that when you click the Send Signal button on `Window1`, you will get `Window2` with the contents of the `QLineEdit` of the first window in the corresponding one in the second window.

If you want these two windows to be linked so that whenever you press that button, the second window's `QLineEdit` will change again to the current text in `Window1`, you can add a simple if else statement in your `send_signal` method inside your first class. You will also need to pass the actual `Window1` class into `Window2`

If it's the first time pressing the button, instantiate the `Window2` class with the current text. If it's the second + time pressing the button, you can emit a signal from class one and change the text in the second class. Here's some code that works this way:

**Linked windows**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Window1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    textSaved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window1,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Signal Signal Emitter")
        self.home()
        self.counter = 0
    def home(self):

        self.__line=QtGui.QLineEdit("howdy", self)
        self.__line.move(120,100)

        btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Send Signal", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.send_signal)
        btn.move(0,100)

        self.show()

    def send_signal(self):
        if self.counter == 0:
            signal=self.__line.displayText()
            self.Window2=Window2(signal, self)
            self.Window2.show()
            self.textSaved.connect(self.Window2.showMessage)
            self.counter = 1
        else:
            signal = self.__line.displayText()
            self.textSaved.emit(signal)

class Window2(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, txt, window1):
        self.text = txt
        self.signal1 = window1.textSaved
        super(Window2,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Signal Slot Receiver")
        self.home()
        self.signal1.connect(self.showMessage)

    def home(self):
        self.line_response=QtGui.QLineEdit(self.text, self)
        self.line_response.move(120,100)

    def showMessage(self, message):
        self.line_response.setText(message)

def run():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI=Window1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
run()
```

If you have any questions, please comment! I wrote this kinda quickly; I will edit with more explanations when I have more time!